# length of the unique elements of listed vectors in R

Tags: r, function

In my `R` function below, I was wondering how I could get the length of the unique elements (which is `2`) of two vectors `a` and `b`?

Here is what I tried without success:

```
foo <- function(...){
    L <- list(...)
    lengths(unique(unlist(L)))
}

a = rep(c("a", "b"), 30) # Vector `a`
b = rep(c("a", "b"), 20) # Vector `b`

foo(a, b)  # the function returns 1 1 instead of 2 2
```

Comment: lengths should maybe be length?

Comment: I think you might check the difference between `length()` and `lengths()`. They both exist but have different abilities.

Comment: result from `lengths` is correct

Comment: I have posted the solution below your outcome should be 60 for a and 40 for b to show the elements inside!

Comment: @DataScience, but that just is for one of the vectors not both. I want it to return 2 2

Comment: My bad - i see you want 2,2 - then that can be achieved by using the assert that argument instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lapply()` or `sapply()` because your object is a list. I think you might check the difference between `length()` and `lengths()`. They both exist but have different abilities. I provide two solutions `foo1` and `foo2`:

```
foo1 <- function(...){
  L <- list(...)
  sapply(L, function(x) length(unique(x)))
}

foo2 <- function(...){
  L <- list(...)
  lengths(lapply(L, unique))
}

a = rep(c("a", "b"), 30) # Vector `a`
b = rep(c("a", "b"), 20) # Vector `b`

foo1(a, b)
# [1] 2 2

foo2(a, b)
# [1] 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

You were using the unlist function - so you were back at the start with the vector lengths!

use this code instead

```
foo <- function(a,b){

  L <- list(a,b)
  lengths(unique(L)) ### this return 1 1

}

a = rep(c("a", "b"), 30) # Vector `a`

b = rep(c("a", "b"), 20) # Vector `b`

foo(a, b)
```